# How to load query to a variable in SQL function and return it

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I`m writing a program with SQL function in PostgreSQL. The purpose of the program is receiving two inputs and return one output in function. I have a table namely 'score' in which 3 columns 1) quid (integer type) 2) sca (integer type) 3) scb (integer type). I send two inputs **quid** and **score**. After that inside function two inputs are initialized to new variables. The problem is I cannot load select query to a new variable and return it. When I send two variables it is giving error. I sent variables using this: **select sendans(2,'b');**
My source code is here:

```
create or replace function sendans(n integer,m text)
returns integer as $$
declare
num1 integer=n;
num2 text=m;
total integer=0;
begin
if num2='a' then
select total = sca from score where quid=num1;
return total;
end if;

if num2='b' then
select total = scb from score where quid=num1;
return total;
end if;

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a column value from a query to a variable in PLpgSQL, you have to use the `SELECT <column> INTO <variable>` syntax. E.g.

```
SELECT sca INTO total
       FROM score
       WHERE quid = num1;
```